# Creating a new meta_type or meta table in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is it actually possible to create a new meta table or meta type in WordPress? I know there is already:

postmeta
commentmeta
usermeta

I am trying to add: sectionmeta. Using postmeta could result in a very large table in such a very short time for my website. So I am a little worried about stability in terms of storing all the data in the postmeta table which is already storing different metadata per post. I will be storing lots of metadata per post letting users take small parts of a post or page and create discussions which I will like to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create a new table. Lots of plugins / themes do this all the time.

You can hook into the saving and the retrieval of posts (or you can define your post type) and add your functionality.

Check out https://github.com/Automattic/custom-metadata

Comment: I am not trying to create a new table. I would like to create a new meta table/meta type using Wordpress functions so that Wordpress registers a new metadata/meta_type and use the metadata functions like metadata add_metadata( $meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value )

Comment: There is a plugin that can help you with that. Check it out and see if it meets your needs (I edited my answer to include link)